# Where does xcode keep its default paths to librarys and headers?

Tags: c++, xcode, header, location

I have a C++ app/project under Linux Eclipse. I started porting to Mac OS X. I use 4 cross-platform C/C++ libraries such as OpenCV, OpenAL Boost etc.

First I installed C++ and Eclipse for Mac. When I opened the project in eclipse it did not find any of my Linux includes. When I opened the code in xcode it solved some - for example OpenAL.

Where does Xcode look for libraries and headers?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head I'd say try the following locations:

- /System/Library/Frameworks
- /System/Library/CoreServices
- /Developer/SDKs

Probably in the first option.

Comment: Note that you may not be able to actually use the files in Eclipse…Apple keeps some of them under lock and key…

Comment: Also, Xcode does support C++. Depending on what you're building, you may want to try to load it into Xcode and work with it there.

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 6.4 and the OSX 10.10 SDK, look here:

- /Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Then expand the OpenAL.framework and double click on the Headers folder.